# PostGIS ST_Intersects result is ignored by where condition

Tags: postgis, intersection, st-intersects

I have a simple query filtering by `st_intersects` function finding all lines intersecting with a polygon.

```
select *, st_intersect(graph_line, st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((261 156,148 452,333 507,566 199,261 156))') 
from graph_schema.graph_line 
where graph_id=<ID> and st_intersect(graph_line, st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((261 156,148 452,333 507,566 199,261 156))')
```

The problem is that for some data where a line is just a point the `st_intersects` returns false even though it intersects. Furthermore even when the result is **false** it is returned in the result.

Examples:

```
select st_intersects(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(480 270,480 270)')::geometry, st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((261 156,148 452,333 507,566 199,261 156))')::geometry);
```

returns **false**, but *where* condition does not filter it when the first parameter is taken from the table - and even when the object should spatialy intersect.

[image]

Is this because of the LINESTRING being just a point? Or what can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input is an invalid geometry, so the output is meaningless.

What you can do is to make the input a valid geometry before using it. [`ST_MakeValid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html) would fix the faulty geom (making them a point) and would keep the valid ones intact.

```sql
select st_intersects(
    st_makeValid(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(480 270,480 270)'),3857)), 
    st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((261 156,148 452,333 507,566 199,261 156))'),3857)
);
 st_intersects
---------------
 t
```